# Getting Direction from Compass

Tags: iphone, compass-geolocation

How do i get the Direction from compass when i rotate my device?
i have use :
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)heading {
}
method but nothing is detected under **heading** tag?

i just want to get the direction (i.e) 90N , 180S etc..

need help
Thank you.

Comment: What device you're testing on? AFAIK compass was added only in 3gs model.

Comment: Do you mean the heading _parameter_ doesn't contain the info you seek?

Comment: Yes iam testing on iphone 3gs and heading parameter contain true and magnetic heading but not the direction north south etc..

Answer (score 0):

There is no direction property, just the heading from north. You have to calculate the direction by yourself.